# how to copy data from file to PostgreSQL using JDBC?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I want to copy data from file to PostgreSQL DB using JDBC. I was using JDBC statement object to copy the file into DB. It is  very slow.

I came to know that we can also use copy out command to copy file to DB. But, how can I do that with JDBC. Even good reference material having an example of copy in JDBC would help.

PS: thanks in advance

Comment: Show us the code, and we might explain why it's slow. In particular, are you using batch updates? Are you using prepared statements?

Comment: yeah, i am doing batch updates.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This works...

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager;
import org.postgresql.core.BaseConnection;

public class PgSqlJdbcCopyStreamsExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if(args.length!=4) {
            System.out.println("Please specify database URL, user, password and file on the command line.");
            System.out.println("Like this: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test test password file");
        } else {

            System.err.println("Loading driver");
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

            System.err.println("Connecting to " + args[0]);
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(args[0],args[1],args[2]);

            System.err.println("Copying text data rows from stdin");

            CopyManager copyManager = new CopyManager((BaseConnection) con);

            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(args[3]);
            copyManager.copyIn("COPY t FROM STDIN", fileReader );

            System.err.println("Done.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [pedal-dialect](https://github.com/eclecticlogic/pedal-dialect) allows you to use the copy command directly with JPA entities.

Comment: The cast `(BaseConnection) con` might not work; in certain cases the connection is wrapped in some other connection type (e.g. when using connection pools or spies). What worked for me was to use `con.unwrap(BaseConnection.class)` instead.

Comment: Thank you! Seems this is the only way to do this via the JDBC

Answer (score 2):

(based on [*aliasmrchips*'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6960503/1915920) answer:) if you have a ***Groovy* environment** (like me using it within *ANT*) you could do it like this (substituting the Oracle specifics with Postgres):

```
// exec.groovy
this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL('${postgres-jdbc-driver-path}')
PgScript.load()

// PgScript.groovy
// (we cannot use the org.postgres.* classes in exec.groovy already!)
import java.io.FileReader
import java.sql.DriverManager
import org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager
import org.postgresql.core.BaseConnection

class PgScript {
    static void load() {        

        DriverManager.getConnection (
            '${jdbc-db-url}', '${db-usr}', '${db-usr-pass}'
        ).withCloseable {conn ->
            new CopyManager((BaseConnection) conn).
                copyIn('COPY t FROM STDIN', new FileReader('${sqlfile}'))
        }
    }
}
```

Based also on this [javaworld.com article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073966/core-java/groovy-scripts-master-their-own-classpath-with-rootloader.html).