# Does flyway migrations support PostgreSQL's COPY?

Tags: database, postgresql, flyway

Having performed a pg_dump of an existing posgresql schema, I have an sql file containing a number of table population statements using the copy.

```
COPY test_table (id, itm, factor, created_timestamp, updated_timestamp, updated_by_user, version) FROM stdin;
1   600 0.000   2012-07-17 18:12:42.360828  2012-07-17 18:12:42.360828  system  0
2   700 0.000   2012-07-17 18:12:42.360828  2012-07-17 18:12:42.360828  system  0
\.
```

Though not standard this is part of PostgreSQL's PLSQL implementation.

Performing a flyway migration (via the maven plugin) I get:

```
[ERROR] Caused by org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unexpected message type 0x50 during COPY from stein
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this just not supported?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is **no**.

The one definite problem is that the parser is currently not able to deal with this special construct.

The other question is **jdbc driver support**. Could you try and see if this syntax generally supported by the jdbc driver with a single createStatement call?

If it is, please file an issue in the issue tracker and I'll extend the parser.

**Update:** This is now supported

Comment: As far as I know, the JDBC driver does not support `COPY .. FROM stdin`. Only COPY from a file.

Comment: The JDBC driver does seem to support the `COPY ... FROM stdin` construct, looking at the classes in the `org.postgresql.copy` package.

Comment: Thanks - the issues I was having made me re-evaluate my approach. However, now I have had a chance to dig a bit further into this, it seems it does not have "simple" JDBC support, being via a CopyManager [answer showing example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958965/how-to-copy-a-data-from-file-to-postgresql-using-jdbc)

Comment: By the way - the short answer was exactly what I was after ;) thanks

Comment: The current version seems to support it somehow.. see http://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/postgresql.html

Answer (score 2):

I have accomplished this for Postgres using

```
public abstract class SeedData implements JdbcMigration {

    protected static final String CSV_COPY_STRING = "COPY %s(%s) FROM STDIN HEADER DELIMITER ',' CSV ENCODING 'UTF-8'";

    protected CopyManager copyManager;

    @Override
    public void migrate(Connection connection) throws Exception {
        log.info(String.format("[%s] Populating database with seed data", getClass().getName()));
        copyManager = new CopyManager((BaseConnection) connection);

        Resource[] resources = scanForResources();

        List<Resource> res = Arrays.asList(resources);
        for (Resource resource : res) {
            load(resource);
        }
    }

    private void load(Resource resource) throws SQLException, IOException {
        String location = resource.getLocation();

        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(location);
        if (inputStream == null) {
            throw new FlywayException("Failure to load seed data. Unable to load from location: " + location);
        }
        if (!inputStream.markSupported()) {
            // Sanity check. We have to be able to mark the stream.
            throw new FlywayException(
                    "Failure to load seed data as mark is not supported. Unable to load from location: " + location);
        }
        // set our mark to something big
        inputStream.mark(1 << 32);

        String filename = resource.getFilename();
        // Strip the prefix (e.g. 01_) and the file extension (e.g. .csv)
        String table = filename.substring(3, filename.length() - 4);
        String columns = loadCsvHeader(location, inputStream);

        // reset to the mark
        inputStream.reset();

        // Use Postgres COPY command to bring it in
        long result = copyManager.copyIn(String.format(CSV_COPY_STRING, table, columns), inputStream);
        log.info(format("   %s - Inserted %d rows", location, result));
    }

    private String loadCsvHeader(String location, InputStream inputStream) {
        try {
            return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)).readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new FlywayException("Failure to load seed data. Unable to load from location: " + location, e);
        }
    }

    private Resource[] scanForResources() throws IOException {
        return new ClassPathScanner(getClass().getClassLoader()).scanForResources(getSeedDataLocation(), "", ".csv");
    }

    protected String getSeedDataLocation() {
        return getClass().getPackage().getName().replace('.', '/');
    }

}
```

To use implement the class with the appropriate classpath

```
package db.devSeedData.dev;

public class v0_90__seed extends db.devSeedData.v0_90__seed {
}
```

All that is needed then is to have CSV files in your classpath under db/devSeedData that follow the format 01_tablename.csv. Columns are extracted from the header line of the CSV.