# for writing: Permission denied in postgres using COPY (SELECT * from <table>) To <filename> DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER";

Tags: postgresql

My requirement is write the csv from postgres table data , then i facing the below issue , please give some tips to resolve this issue.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not open file
```

when i use this query

```
COPY (SELECT * from <table>) To <filename> DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER";
```

Comment: Have you read the [fine COPY manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)?

Comment: @dinesh `COPY (SELECT * from mytable) To 'C:\csvfilename.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER";`

Comment: give `write` permission to `postgres` user

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be using PgJDBC.

Most likely you want to use [the `CopyManager`](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html), obtained from `PGConnection`, to `COPY` to/from the Java client. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6958965/398670), and the [PgJDBC API docs](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/index.html).

If you instead intend to do `COPY` to and from the server file system, you must assign appropriate file system permissions so that the user the PostgreSQL server runs as - usually `postgres` - can read/write the desired locations.

Answer (score 1):

Save file where every user can. In this case user postgres.

```
Copy (Select * From tablename To '/tmp/file.csv' With CSV DELIMITER ',';
```