# Load CSV file to a mysql table using Load data into. How do I convert the following query into JOOQ?

Tags: java, mysql, csv, jooq

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/testing.csv'
IGNORE INTO TABLE Test_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS (@col1)
SET test_ID="100",
    test_reg_ID ="26003",
    VALUE =@col1;
```

**testing.csv:**

[image]

TABLE Test_table

[image]

Question No.1: Help me convert this into JOOQ 3.6
Question No.2: I want to avoid the empty data which falls on row 1.

Comment: Thou shalt not use image links in question. Thou shalt post the code as text.

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ has a [CSV import API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/importing/importing-csv/) for that purpose. Here's how you'd translate that MySQL command to jOOQ:

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .loadInto(TEST_TABLE)
   .loadCSV(new File("/testing.csv"))
   .fields(TEST_TABLE.VALUE)
   .separator(',')
// Available in jOOQ 3.10 only: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5737
// .lineSeparator("\n")
   .ignoreRows(1)
   .execute();
```

Note that jOOQ's Loader API doesn't support those default expressions as MySQL does (see [#5740](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5740)):

```
SET test_ID="100",
    test_reg_ID ="26003"
```

There are a few workarounds:

1. You could patch the CSV data and prepend those columns before loading them.
2. You could use [`DSLContext.fetchFromCSV()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#fetchFromCSV-java.lang.String-) and then use `stream().map()` to prepend the missing data, before using the alternative [Record import API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/importing/importing-records/) rather than the suggested [CSV import API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/importing/importing-csv/)
3. You could run a simple `UPDATE` statement right after the import for this data.

#### A note on performance

Do note that jOOQ's loader API can be fine-tuned by specifying [bulk, batch, and commit sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29750635/521799). Nevertheless, the database's out-of-the-box import implementation is very likely to still be much faster than any client side import that has to go through JDBC.