# PostgreSQL - \copy command

Tags: java, postgresql, csv

I tried the above code. I manage to Compile. However, when I run, it give me error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
Position: 1
```

It shows that the query that I run is wrong:

`String query ="\\COPY tmp from 'E:\\load.csv' delimiter ',';";`

The `System.out.println` for the query is: 
`query string: \COPY tmp from 'E:\load.csv' delimiter ',';`

I run the query : `\COPY tmp from 'E:\load.csv' delimiter ',';` in PostgresSQL client, it works.

What happened?

```
Class.forName (driver);
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host+dbname,user,password);
stmt = (java.sql.Statement) conn.createStatement();

//
PreparedStatement prepareUpdater = null;

conn.setAutoCommit(false);

String query ="\\COPY tmp from 'E:\\load.csv' delimiter ',';";

System.out.print("query string: "+query);

System.out.println("Query:"+query);
prepareUpdater = conn.prepareStatement(query);
prepareUpdater.executeUpdate();
prepareUpdater.close();
```

Comment: The command is COPY, there is no backslash

Comment: the actual command that I need to run is \COPY

if I put COPY only, I can load the .csv file to table - error must be a super user

Comment: \COPY Is a psql internal command, not an SQL command. Only psql understands it.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL `COPY` statement exists in two mutation - server side `COPY` and `psql` side `\copy`. Both statements has same syntax and very similar behave. There are significant difference - `\copy` is working with client side file system. `COPY` is working with server side file system. `psql` `\copy` should not be called as server side SQL command. It is used directly from `psql` or from some `bash` scripts.

Server side `COPY` is used for massive export/import operation. When it working with file system, then it can be used only by user with super user rights. Unprivileged users has to use `stdin`, `stdout` target, but application have to support [COPY API](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-copy.html).

`psql` supports it - so you can use it for copy some table from one table to other table:

```
psql -c "COPY mytab TO stdout" db1 | psql -c "COPY targettab FROM stdin" db2
```

For Java Environment, you have to use some support like [CopyManager](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html). See [how to copy a data from file to PostgreSQL using JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958965/how-to-copy-a-data-from-file-to-postgresql-using-jdbc)

Import by `COPY` statement can be significantly faster than by `INSERT` statements - but in dependency on some additional overhead - The difference will be large on plain table without lot of indexes and without slow triggers. If you have lot of indexes on table or slower triggers, then the speedup from `COPY` will be marginal.

Comment: The OP is very obviously about working in a Windows operating system with Java, so an example using `psql` with `stdin` and `stdout` is irrelevant.

Comment: This `Unprivileged users has to use stdin, stdout target` is very helpful while most posts only says superuser rights are required. Is there any official document about this? Thanks.

Comment: @Richard https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html

Comment: @PavelStehule Thank you. copy the part here hoping it helps other people.
`COPY naming a file or command is only allowed to database superusers or users who are granted one of the roles` ......
`Do not confuse COPY with the psql instruction \copy. \copy invokes COPY FROM STDIN or COPY TO STDOUT, and then fetches/stores the data in a file accessible to the psql client. Thus, file accessibility and access rights depend on the client rather than the server when \copy is used.`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your feedback.

I managed to load *.csv using CSVReader.

I download CSVReader package and include it in my codes.

Its working fine.

```
 CsvReader products = new CsvReader("/tmp/ip2location/IP-COUNTRY-REGION-CITY-LATITUDE-LONGITUDE-ISP-DOMAIN-MOBILE-USAGETYPE.CSV");

             products.readHeaders();

             while (products.readRecord())
             {
                String ip_from = products.get("ip_from"); //int
                String ip_to = products.get("ip_to"); //int


                PreparedStatement prepareStat = null;

                String sqlIinsert = "insert into ip2location_tmp(ip_from, ip_to )"
        + " VALUES ("+ip_from+","+ip_to+");";

                System.out.println("sqlInsert:"+sqlIinsert);
                prepareStat = conn.prepareStatement(sqlIinsert); 
                prepareStat.executeUpdate();  

               }
        products.close();
        }enter code here
```

Comment: Your usage of the `PreparedStatement` is completely wrong (and inefficient). You should only prepare it **once** before the while loop using placeholders. Then inside the loop use `setString()` to provide the actual values before calling `executeUpdate()`.

Answer (score 0):

You use `COPY` instead of `/COPY`

> String query ="COPY tmp from 'E://load.csv' delimiter ','";

It will work

Answer (score -2):

The [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) SQL command reads a file from the local file system and the server process must have access to it.

The [`\copy`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY) command is a `psql` instruction and is only available within that environment. You cannot use that in a SQL query.

Since Java has a good CSV reader class, you could simply read the file in your code and then use individual `INSERT` commands to load the data in the database. This is effectively what `\copy` does when working in `psql`.

Comment: Individual INSERTS will be significantly slowly than COPY. Usually it depends on size, but for massive import it is not good advice.

Comment: @PavelStehule That is very true but not a solution to the question. And I do not read anything in the OP that suggests this might be a massive csv file.

Comment: I disagree with sentence "This is effectively what \copy does when working in psql" - sure it depends on details - but it is confusing little bit

Comment: Also COPY is supporting inserting into a table. Check COPY table_name   FROM  'filename'