# Get results as CSV from postgresql using hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, csv

I execute a query which should return the results as a CSV to the STDOUT.

When I execute my query in the pgAdmin I successfully get results.

However when I execute the same query using hibernate I gets the following exception:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet

I mustn't show the tables structure but I know that the sql is fine(I've copied the entire content of "sql" then I execute it in pgAdmin); The query looks like:

```
String sql = "COPY (" + sqlQuery + ") TO STDOUT WITH CSV";
```

Then I execute it as the following:

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sql);

Object result = query.getSingleResult(); // I also tried the other get results method...(`getFirstresult()` has returned 0)
```

In any related questions I have found, I saw that the OP put the csv into a file instead of stdout.

Is it possible to return csv result using hibernate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why use Hibernate here?  A simple JDBC query (or plus a CSV library) should be much easier.

Comment: @AdrianShum That's the way I'm going to solve this issue... I just want to make sure that it is not possible using Hibernate... Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, `COPY` is not supported natively by PostgreSQL JDBC driver (last tested on `postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7`). Thus, Hibernate can not run the command.

If you really need to use `COPY` you should consider a `CopyManager`: [how to copy a data from file to PostgreSQL using JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958965/how-to-copy-a-data-from-file-to-postgresql-using-jdbc)

But personally, I would advocate you change your approach. Loading data with `COPY` looks like a kind of a hack to me.

Comment: Thank you very much for the awesome answer! :) Beside the accept, I'd vote up but I don't have enough reputation...

Answer (score 0):

You can have this done with [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) using two lines of code. You just need to get a resultset from your query and do this:

```
CsvRoutines routines = new CsvRoutines();
routines.write(resultset, new File("/path/to/output.csv"), "UTF-8");
```

The write() method takes care of everything. The resultset is closed by the routine automatically.